# Recursive item movement in SQL

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I am attempting to show a cumulative count of all items per month filtered by the status of the item - 'raw', 'finished', 'lost'.Database I am using is PostgreSQL. My lastest query at the bottom is close to what I am looking for but I want to show the total count per 'status' even if not entries exist for that month. Currently in month 3,4 and 5 - the count is blank. Would lag/lead work here? Or perhaps another approach.
I've tried to illustrate the issue as simple as possible.

Example:

```
id  created_at  lastmodified    closed_at   status
1   2/22/2016   6/21/2016                     Raw
2   2/4/2016    6/21/2016                     Raw
3   8/21/2016   8/26/2016                     Raw
4   8/12/2016   8/26/2016                     Raw
5   2/8/2016    6/21/2016                     Raw
6   8/2/2016    8/26/2016                     Raw
7   6/14/2016   6/29/2016   6/23/2016       Finished
8   2/12/2016   6/21/2016                     Raw
9   8/18/2016   8/26/2016                     Raw
10  8/8/2016    8/26/2016   8/26/2016       Finished
11  8/26/2016   8/26/2016                     Raw
12  8/5/2016    8/26/2016                     Raw
13  2/30/2016   2/30/2016   2/30/2016       Finished
14  6/22/2016   7/19/2016   7/27/2016       Finished
15  8/12/2016   8/28/2016                     Raw
16  9/20/2016   10/16/2016                    Raw
17  2/15/2016   6/11/2016                     Raw
18  2/6/2016    9/24/2016                     Lost
```

I want to show a bar chart depicting the movement of items through time, on a monthly basis, (say from 01-16 to 04-16, in this example) such that item3 will also have an entry for 02-16 of raw for which it does not have an entry for in the database but since its last known status is 'raw' should be accounted for.
I believe a CTE(common-table-expression) is needed to generate a date table to consume all dates within the given period.

```
with dates as(
select * from generate_series('2016-01-01'::date,
  '2017-04-01'::date,
  '1 day'::interval)
```

Query results should look like, basically a running count at the end of each month of how total of all items there were at each status.

```
month/yr       raw     finished     lost
2/2016          5          1        0
3/2016          6          0        0
4/2016          7          0        0
5/2016          7          0        0
6/2016          8          2        0
7/2016          7          3        0
8/2016          13         4        0
9/2016          13         0        1
sum             13         4        1
```

There are three stages - raw, finished, lost.You are correct to assume that `raw` can only have either create_at or modified_at, while `finished` - can have all three fields filled `created_at`, `modified_at` and `closed_at`. However closed_at will only be filled when the status changes to `finished`. `Lost` items can also only have either `created_at` or `modifieddate`. All items when they are created attain the status of `raw` by default.
Items that attain a status of `finished` will never get another date entry but I would like to show the cumulative number of items for that status.

```
WITH dates as(
    SELECT * FROM generate_series('2016-02-01'::date, '2016-06-01'::date,
  '1 month'::interval)
),
step AS (
    SELECT a.Id, 
    'Raw' AS Step,
    a.Created_at AS FDate,
    b.TDate
    FROM sales a
    LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
    a.Id,
    CASE WHEN a.lastmodified IS NULL THEN now() ELSE a.lastmodified END AS TDate
    FROM sales a
    WHERE a.lastmodified IS NOT NULL AND a.Status like 'Raw') b
    ON a.Id = b.Id
    WHERE a.created_at IS NOT NULL

    UNION
    SELECT a.Id,  
    'Lost' AS Step,
    a.lastmodified AS FDate,
    b.TDate
    FROM sales a
    LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT a.Id, 
    CASE WHEN a.lastmodified IS NULL THEN now() ELSE a.lastmodified END AS ToDate
    FROM sales a
    WHERE a.closed_at IS NOT NULL AND a.Status like 'Finished') b
    ON a.Id = b.Id
    WHERE a.lastmodified IS NOT NULL AND a.Status like 'Lost'

    UNION
    SELECT a.Id, 
    'Finished' AS Step,
    a.closed_at::date AS FDate,
    now() AS TDate
    FROM sales a
    WHERE a.closed_at IS NOT NULL AND a.Status like 'Finished'
)
    SELECT DISTINCT to_char(d.generate_series::date, 'YYYY-MM') AS date, s.Step AS Status,
    COUNT(s.Step) OVER (PARTITION BY s.Step ORDER BY to_char(d.generate_series, 'YYYY-MM')) AS count_id
    FROM dates d
    LEFT JOIN step s
    ON to_char(d.generate_series::date,'YYYY-MM') = to_char(s.FDate::date, 'YYYY-MM')
    ORDER BY date ASC
```

This query brings me quite close to what I am looking for. However, I have a count of zero for month where no items were created, modified or closed. I want to show the cumulative count of the previous month if no entries exist. How would I accomplish this? Would lag/lead work here?

Comment: What do you want the query result to look like? Ignore the chart, that's a totally different question.

Comment: Why does 01-01-2016 show 3?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because you not produced enough information to answer it.

Comment: @EvanCarroll - hey I believe I now have the information that to answer this inquiry. thanks for your help and assistance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like

1. everything that isn't `finished`, is `raw`
2. `finished` can only have `closed_at`
3. `raw` can only have `created_at` and `modified_at`
4. You want us to assume things are `raw` for all points in time prior to `created_at`
5. You want things to show finished after that point in time as finished?

Please clarify what you want. Preferably show sample data and an end result.

All of that said, I think what you want is something similar to this

```
SELECT d, CASE WHEN d < stat.min THEN 'raw' ELSE 'finished' END
FROM ( VALUES
  ('2016-01-01'::date, '2017-04-01'::date)
) AS t(date_start,date_end)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(date_start, date_end, '1 day')
  AS gs(d)
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT min(closed_at)
  FROM foo
  WHERE item_id = 'item3'
  GROUP BY item_id
) AS stat;
```